# Equaling Integers

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am creating Binary Tree. I can't equals Integers, but in my lesson it works. Here's a part of code:

```
In tree...

public void add(BTree<T> tree, T newValue){

    if(newValue.equals(getValue())){
        System.out.println("equals, incrementing count...");
        tree.count.incrementAndGet();
    }else if(newValue.compareTo(tree.getValue()) > 0){
        addRight(tree, newValue);
                    //It will back here with another node
    }else{
        addLeft(tree, newValue);
                    //It will back here with another node
    }
}

In main...

BTree<Integer> tree = new BTree<>(0);
    tree.add(tree, 1);
    tree.add(tree, 1);
    tree.add(tree, 1);
    tree.add(tree, -1);

    System.out.println(tree.getLeftChild().getValue() + "(" + tree.getLeftChild().getCount() + ")"  + "     " + tree.getRightChild().getValue() + "(" + tree.getRightChild().getCount() + ")");

In console...

-1(1)     1(1)
```

How can I equals two VALUES ?

Comment: _How can I equals two VALUES ?_  **using properly implemented `equals()` method**

Comment: *if(newValue.equals(getValue()))*   What is getValue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that your definition of `equals` is not consistent with `compareTo`. This is not a good thing.

Although you can work around it by using `compareTo` exclusively, like this:

```
int cmpResult = newValue.compareTo(tree.getValue();
if (cmpResult == 0){
    System.out.println("equals, incrementing count...");
    tree.count.incrementAndGet();
}else if(cmpResult > 0){
    addRight(tree, newValue);
}else{
    addLeft(tree, newValue);
}
```

[Java documentation for the `Comparable` interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) strongly recommends you to fix the problem:

> It is strongly recommended (though not required) that natural orderings be consistent with `equals`. This is so because sorted sets (and sorted maps) without explicit comparators behave "strangely" when they are used with elements (or keys) whose natural ordering is inconsistent with `equals`. In particular, such a sorted set (or sorted map) violates the general contract for set (or map), which is defined in terms of the `equals` method.

Comment: Thank you! Error was in "tree." than wasn't writed )